# Understanding Bus Architecture Terminology

Tags: motherboard, architecture, fsb, bus

I've read several books which talked about bus architectures. Each one uses a myriad of terms. Can someone help sort these out for me?

system bus
external data bus
internal data bus
front-side bus
back-side bus

Some books says that everything travels on the external data bus, whereas others include the internal data bus.

Is there one big name for all the buses combined, and then they are divided into the other buses (memory, pci, fsb, etc.)?

Where does the system clock come into all of this?

Comment: Explaining this is a bit like explaining how a road fits in traffic. It would have to be a real broad answer to fully answer all questions.

Comment: Well, I said simple in order to cut down on people having to write long answers. However, I can handle more complicated answers just fine I believe.